# How to use Fluent style syntactic sugar with c# property declaration

Tags: c#, fluent

I never used the fluent code style before. So this is hte first time I tried to develop something in the fluent style with a C# property declaration, but I get an error. Can anyone help me?

```
public class MailTemplate
{
    string _MailBody = "";
    public MailTemplate MailBody
    {
        get { return _MailBody; }
        set { _MailBody = value ; }
    }

    string _Subject = "";
    public MailTemplate Subject
    {
        get { return _Subject; }
        set { _Subject = value; }
    }

    string _MailFrom = "";
    public MailTemplate MailFrom
    {
        get { return _MailFrom; }
        set { _MailFrom = value; }
    }
}
```

Please help me how I could assign or initialize the mail body and later also can read with same property name. I think a property cannot be used in case of fluent style development. Need some light here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A fluent builder interface for the `MailTemplate` class would look something like this:

```
public class MailTemplateBuilder
{
    string _body;
    string _subject;
    string _sender;

    public MailTemplateBuilder WithBody(string body)
    {
        _body = body;
        return this;
    }

    public MailTemplateBuilder WithSubject(string subject)
    {
        _subject = subject;
        return this;
    }

    public MailTemplateBuilder WithSender(string sender)
    {
        _sender = sender;
        return this;
    }

    public MailTemplate Build()
    {
        return new MailTemplate(_sender, _subject, _body);
    }
}
```

Usage would look like this:

```
var template = _builder.WithBody("body")
                       .WithSubject("subject")
                       .WithSender("sender")
                       .Build();
```

---

Another approach would be to use extension methods:

```
public static class MailTemplateBuilder
{
    public static MailTemplate WithBody(this MailTemplate item, string body)
    {
        item.MailBody = body;
        return item;
    }

    public static MailTemplate WithSubject(this MailTemplate item, string subject)
    {
        item.MailSubject = subject;
        return item;
    }

    public static MailTemplate WithSender(this MailTemplate item, string sender)
    {
        item.MailFrom = sender;
        return item;
    }
}
```

Usage would now look like this:

```
var template = new MailTemplate().WithBody("body")
                                 .WithSubject("subject")
                                 .WithSender("sender");
```

**Please note:**
In both cases, the `MailTemplate` class is not polluted with code for this fluent interface. It would be a simple class:

```
public class MailTemplate
{
    public string MailBody { get; set; } = "";
    public string Subject { get; set; } = "";
    public string MailFrom { get; set; } = "";
}
```

So, after you created that instance with any one of the provided fluent interfaces, you can simply read the values by accessing the properties:

```
var body = template.MailBody;
```

Comment: What's the need of build() method in this case? It works just like an old clone method

Comment: @djechelon: No. Look again, there are two classes here. A builder and the actual template. I don't like poluting the model with code for a fluent interface.

Comment: i just need to know how could i read back the data. suppose WithBody("body") i can set data with WithBody("body") but how could i read back.

Comment: @Thomas: Please see update of my answer. I added the code of your `MailTemplate` class and showed how to read the values.

Comment: `public string MailBody    { get; set; }` better ?

Answer (score 4):

Some frameworks e.g. FluentNHibernate just pass themselves as a lambda for this:

```cs
MailTemplate
    .ConfigureWith(mt => mt.MailBody = "hello world")
    .ConfigureWith(mt => mt.MailFrom = "rdingwall@gmail.com")
    .DoSomeOtherStuff()
    .Build();
```

The implementation for this would be:

```cs
public class MailTemplate
{
    // regular auto properties
    public string MailFrom { get; set; }
    public string MailBody { get; set; }

    public MailTemplate ConfigureWith(Action<MailTemplate> func)
    {
        func(this);
        return this;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: your ConfigureWith() function expects one delegate but when u use the code like .ConfigureWith(mt => mt.MailBody = "hello world") it means you are passing string data to ConfigureWith() function but it expects one delegate. it is bit confusing for me. can u tell how it works. thanks

Comment: another important thing is can i use your code in .net version 2.0 ??

Comment: when i am trying to compile your code in c# v2.0 then i am getting error. c# 2.0 does not support lambda?

Comment: It's called a lambda expression, it's a shorthand form of a delegate that's easier to read. In this case, assigning a string value to a property. And yes I just checked, it compiles fine in VS2010 targeting .NET 2.0.

Comment: ConfigureWith not static. `new MailTemplate().ConfigureWith` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use properties like that to write a fluent interface - the fields are of type `string` but your properties all try to return a `MailTemplate`.

Instead of properties, make these into *methods* that can be chained together.

```
public class MailTemplate
{
    string _MailBody = "";

    public MailTemplate Body(string mailBody)
    {
        _MailBody = mailBody;
        return this;
    }

    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Richard said, **FluentNHibernate** just pass themselves as a lambda. you can also do the same using **c#**.

```
public class MailTemplate
{
   
    public string To { get; set; }
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string Attachement { get; set; }

    public static MailTemplate Configure { get => new MailTemplate(); }


    public MailTemplate With(Action<MailTemplate> func)
    {
        func(this);
        return this;
    }

    internal void Build()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sending the mail....");
    }
}
```

This is how to call this method

```
MailTemplate
            .Configure
                .With(mt => mt.To = "michaelameyaw7@gmail.com")
                .With(mt => mt.From = "persol.system@gmail.com")
                .With(mt => mt.Subject = "Fluent Try Test")
                .With(mt => mt.Body = "Hello, this is mail body")
                .With(mt => mt.Attachement = "file.pdf")
           .Build();
```